# VB big block of text?

Tags: vb.net, label

Is there a way of putting a block of text (ie a paragraph) without using the label tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim myString As String = "Hello world " + ControlChars.NewLine + _
" trying the next line of code " + ControlChars.NewLine + _
" trying the third line of code..."

Label1.Text = myString
```

Fixed, this works for me.

Comment: how can i get it to display it in the program itself? do i call it from the label?

Comment: Edited to fix the problem with the "_"

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of winform or webform, you can store your very large text in a file and use [System.IO.File.File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) Method to read that block of text and assign the read text to relevant control.